# Efficient way to find maximum number in previous N numbers in an array

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a super large array called **A**.

I would like to find a result array R, which:

R[i] = **max(A[i - X]:A[i + 1])**.

For example, A=[5,7,1,4,3,9,6,2,5,5,10], X=2.

Then result would be R = [5,7,7,7,4,9,9,9,6,5,10]

as

..

R[2] = A[2-2:3] = max(5,7,1) = 7

R[3] = A[3-2:4] = max(7,1,4) = 7

R[4] = A[5-2:5] = max(1,4,3) = 4

...

If A is like 10 billion numbers, and X is like 1000, what is the most efficient way to find the result?

The best I can think of is just creating a priority queue to store/remove the max number when looping A.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand how from `A=[5,7,1,4,3,9,6,2,5,5,10], X=2` you get `result = [5,7,7,7,4,9,9,9,6,5,10]`. In example, R[2] should be 5, not 7, since `A[2 - 2]` is equal to 5 and `A[2 + 1]` is equal to 4.

Comment: I added an example to find R[2], R[3], R[4]

Comment: Ah okay, that wasn't clear, I didn't got that it was a range of indexes

Comment: It's the subarray from A's index i-X to i+1

Comment: As dumb answer, I would use threads to improve the efficience, since you won't write the same index at the same time

Comment: But yeah, I think the best would be to enqueue/dequeue, it will save a lot of time and memory